# Can't locate my firebase config file inside a docker container

Tags: firebase, docker, go

I am trying to import my firebase config file into my golang application like so

```golang
configfile := "internal/pkg/utils/firebase/firebaseConfig.json"
opt := option.WithCredentialsFile(configFile)
```

However, I keep running into this error when I run my application inside Docker:

```
"open "internal/pkg/utils/firebase/firebaseConfig.json": no such file or directory".
```

When I compile on my machine and run it, it works perfectly fine. The file is located and my authentication client is initialized. I tried going inside the docker container to make sure that my file exists at `/app/internal/pkg/utils/firebase/` and it does.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.22

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./ 
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . .

RUN go build -o ./bin/tamra ./cmd/tamra/

# Command to run the executable
CMD ["./bin/tamra", "-port=8080", "-db=postgres://postgres:mysecretpassword@db:5432/tamra-postgis?sslmode=disable", "-log-level=debug", "-firebase-config=internal/pkg/utils/firebase/firebaseConfig.json"]
```

Comment: Can you please show us how you are trying to connect with the  `firebaseConfig.json`? Also [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help us to replicate the error on our end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your project is laid out like this (missing many files that you might have):

```
├── Dockerfile
└── internal
    └── pkg
        └── utils
            └── firebase
                └── firebaseConfig.json
```

I can confirm that the file is where you would expect it to be on the container.

So this leads me to suspect that there is something in your Go code which is causing the problem. Can you share a stripped down version of your application that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: After a grueling debugging session, the issue was in my docker-compose.yml file. I had this environment variable "-FIREBASE_CONFIG="internal/pkg/utils/firebase/firebaseConfig.json". The Firebase library looks for this environment variable first before checking the file name that I explicitly pass in the code. I simply had to remove the quotations around that environment variable and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Look once inside the container all in all you are in new world of container Operating System.

try with absolute path.

-firebase-config=/app/internal/pkg/utils/firebase/firebaseConfig.json

Comment: Oh, believe me, I tried that. Thanks though! I managed to resolve it. It was an issue of having quotations around the environment variable inside of my docker-compose. I replied to datawookie above.